# Issue with TextBox

Tags: android

I have the following code:

```
public class Chat_Room extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btn_send_msg;
    private EditText input_msg;
    private TextView chat_conversation;

    private String user_name,room_name;
    private DatabaseReference root;
    private String temp_key;
    private String str;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chat_room);

        btn_send_msg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button13);
        input_msg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        chat_conversation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        user_name = getIntent().getExtras().get("user_name").toString();
        room_name = getIntent().getExtras().get("room_name").toString();
        setTitle("Chat Room - " + room_name);

        root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(room_name);

        str=input_msg.getText().toString().trim();

        btn_send_msg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(str != null && !str.isEmpty()){
                    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    temp_key = root.push().getKey();
                    root.updateChildren(map);

                    DatabaseReference message_root = root.child(temp_key);
                    Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    map2.put("name", user_name);
                    map2.put("msg", input_msg.getText().toString());

                    message_root.updateChildren(map2);

                    input_msg.setText("");
                }else{
                    /// show the error msg to the user
                    Toast.makeText(Chat_Room.this, "Please enter the message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });


        root.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                append_chat_conversation(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                append_chat_conversation(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
    private String chat_msg,chat_user_name;
    private void append_chat_conversation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

        while (i.hasNext()){

            chat_msg = (String) ((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();
            chat_user_name = (String) ((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();

            chat_conversation.append(chat_user_name + " - " + chat_msg + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to output an error when a user doesn't type text in the textbox, but with text in it, it still sends the error message.
So basically, I was able to create the error that I wanted so that when the button is pressed in the chat room to send a blank message it responds with an error. However, even when I type something in the textbox and try to send it, it is responding with the same error and not sending the message. So please can you help!

Comment: I usually don't know much about android, but you only set the value of str in your onCreate Method. Shouldn't `str=input_msg.getText().toString().trim();` be inside your onClick method so that it reads the string with every click instead of just once at creation?

Comment: @911DidBush I think I provided the same info in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be reading the `EditText` on `Button` click? You are doing it `onCreate()` of `Activity`..I doubt that something is written there already at start of App / launch of Activity. So once you tap SEND, it won't store any text..because your `str` will be `null` ..hence onCreate() there was nothing in `EditText` to store in `str`.

Even if you later write something in..you're not trying to get that Text.

Try moving `str=input_msg.getText().toString().trim();` into `onButtonClick()` just before you check if `str` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

As said, your `String str` is null. Use inside the `OnClick` Event :

```
btn_send_msg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        str=input_msg.getText().toString().trim(); // <--- here

        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(username)){
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            temp_key = root.push().getKey();
            root.updateChildren(map);

            DatabaseReference message_root = root.child(temp_key);
            Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map2.put("name", user_name);
            map2.put("msg", input_msg.getText().toString());

            message_root.updateChildren(map2);

            input_msg.setText("");
        }else{
            /// show the error msg to the user
            Toast.makeText(Chat_Room.this, "Please enter the message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
});
```